# handle multiple request from client and send relevent response back

Tags: java, multithreading, finance, trading

I have to design a system in java, which will have an trade data exchange (contains the trade data), a server and N number of clients. The scenario is the server gets requests from N number of clients to get the trade data, the server is having 6 connections between server and exchange, server send request to exchange on one connection and receive the output on other connection.

- How do i design the system so the relevant output can send back to client with high performance?
- How many number of threads do i need?
- How can this small scenario handle at its best?

Please suggest.

Comment: Please mark as homework if appropriate.

Comment: Reads like homework, feels like homework - must be homework...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you set up a client handler class to facilitate the communication between each individual client and the server.  Basically for every client connected to that server there is a client handler that communicates with it.

Things you might need to think about are thread synchronization if data that is accessed by the client's is all the same.  For instance if each client was going to read and write information to the same file you would need to synchronize the access to the file.

Answer (score -1):

What about a unique client/session ID generated by the server? (Find out the rest.)